# Can't use npx create-react-app <APP> as it return ETIMEDOUT

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

I know I know, there are already a lot of topics like this one, but I need to give it a try because I can't find the answer.

So, I installed Node.js, following the advice, adding the path to an environment variable, downloading every package, and after that first shot, I got to see an `ERR! code ETIMEDOUT` error for the first time.

After that I started my search for a solution, which led me to do the following:

```
npm install create-react-app
npm config delete proxy
npm config delete https proxy
npm config delete http proxy
npm cache clean --force
npm install npm@latest -g
npm init react-app
npx create-react-app <app> -timeout=60000
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
npm config rm https-proxy
npm config rm proxy
```

Not only did I spend a lot of time trying to find a solution online, I also used the Huggingface dataset to build an embedding model with GPT-3 to extract and retrieve useful information about coding in Node.js, just to find out why it's not working, and still, I don't have the answer.

And now I don't know what to do next.

here is log file:

```html
0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@8.19.3
2 info using node@v18.13.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 2ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 3ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 2ms
10 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\USERNAME\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
14 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load Completed in 12ms
18 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 12ms
19 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 0ms
20 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 0ms
21 verbose title npm install npm@latest
22 verbose argv "install" "npm@latest" "--global"
23 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
24 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 3ms
25 timing npm:load:display Completed in 4ms
26 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs
27 verbose logfile C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-01-30T11_25_07_524Z-debug-0.log
28 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 6ms
29 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
30 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
31 timing npm:load Completed in 23ms
32 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 2 files
33 silly logfile done cleaning log files
34 timing command:install Completed in 133203ms
35 verbose type system
36 verbose stack FetchError: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/npm failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700::6810:1423:80
36 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\index.js:130:14)
36 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
36 verbose stack     at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:496:9)
36 verbose stack     at Socket.emit (node:events:525:35)
36 verbose stack     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
36 verbose stack     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
36 verbose stack     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
37 verbose cwd C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\MY APP
38 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19044
39 verbose node v18.13.0
40 verbose npm  v8.19.3
41 error code ETIMEDOUT
42 error syscall connect
43 error errno ETIMEDOUT
44 error network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/npm failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700::6810:1423:80
45 error network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
45 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
45 error network
45 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
45 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
46 verbose exit 1
47 timing npm Completed in 133331ms
48 verbose code 1
49 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

WHAT WORKED : npm config set registry https://registry.npm.taobao.org
source :
https://www.programmersought.com/article/67016822875/
[Facing issue when tried running npx create-react-app myapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63014014/facing-issue-when-tried-running-npx-create-react-app-myapp)

Best,
KL

### Heading

Comment: I have tried disabling ipv6 and it's worked https://stackoverflow.com/a/74968367/12280326

Answer (score 0):

Here is alternative command to create react app

```
npm init react-app app-name
```